# Delphi XE Reportman

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, reportmanager

Does anybody know if http://reportman.sourceforge.net/ will be available for Delphi XE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to get [Reportmanager 2.9b](http://reportman.sourceforge.net/) to install and run under Delphi XE by adding the following lines to the file **`rpconf.inc`**.

```
// Delphi XE
{$IFDEF VER220}
  {$DEFINE UNICODE}
  {$DEFINE DELPHI2009UP}
  {$DEFINE INDY10}
  {$DEFINE INDY10_2}
  {$DEFINE DELPHI2006UP}
  {$DEFINE DELPHI2007UP}
{$ENDIF}
```

Regards, Pieter

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this project, but it is GNU/MPL Licensed, it means you can do it by yourself.

As it is available for delphi 2009, if you have some experience dealing with components and packages it is almost trivial to upgrade it to compile with delphi XE.

If not, you can [ask the author](http://reportman.sourceforge.net/contrib.html) (or hire someone else) to do the upgrade on your behalf.

Comment: I have asked the author nut so far I have not had any replies. I'll certainly try to upgrade it to XE.